# Synthesizing Kylo Ren Voice in Mathematica - Start Wars

Tags: sound

Kylo Ren voice in [Star Wars The Force Awakens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens) is very cool. When I watched the movie in 2015, one of the first things that came up to my mind was how to do such voice in Mathematica. At the time Mathematica capabilities to manipulate sounds were very simplistic, and was not possible to do such thing.

I'm far far way to be a sound expert, but I tried do something like this:

```
file = Import["https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rmurta/murta-audio.wav"];
audioOrg = Audio[file];
audioKylo = AudioPitchShift[audioOrg, 0.9];
audioKylo = AudioFrequencyShift[audioKylo,-200]//AudioAmplify[#, 4]&
```

Original Murta's record: [Murta original](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rmurta/murta-audio.wav)

And here is the result: [Murta as Kylo](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rmurta/murta-kylo-audio.wav)

[image: Kyle Ren scene]
[youtube link for Kyle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy-wqB4cbT8&feature=youtu.be&t=49s)

[- Cross post in Wolfram -](http://community.wolfram.com/)

I believe the community can do much better. I'm right?

Comment: How many wars shall we start? And against who? ;o)